# Best way to integrate an XMPP Server into Webapplication

Tags: xmpp

I'm working on a middle size community project, using php and the php framework symfony2 atm.

We are planning to integrate XMPP as a support chat and premium feature for our users. The users will be able to connect via a webclient and also via normal xmpp clients.

So here are my questions:

1. About the Rosters: I want to have the users from the friends list listed in the users contact list. I know that this can be done with rosters. But how can I implement this on a simple and stable way? Is there a good Server implementation that can get the users roster out of a sql database like pgsql?
2. What happens on the client when the roster datas are beeing changed while the user is logged in on the xmpp server?
3. Can I group the users that are listed in the roster of a user?
4. Which XMPP server project would you recommend for that kind of project?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. most existing XMPP servers support all popular DBRMs. So this should be no problem.
2. probably nothing when you make the changes directly do the database. So have to find a server where you can initiate a roster push to all connected clients. See also the XMPP RFCs for roster updates.
3. yes, roster groups are a core feature of XMPP.
4. You can find a list of XMPP servers here: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/ You have to check which servers support pgsql and allow you to update the roster and initiate the roster pushes to connected resources.